# How to use onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() in a widget?

Tags: android

I would like to update my widget every time it gets resized. I figured out that this is done in:

`onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)`

But I can't find out how to update the widget in it. I tried to redraw the widget by calling everything that I put in `onUpdate()`, but it's not working. How can I make use of the bundle?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I would like to update my widget every time it gets resized.

Cool!

> I figured out that this is done in `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()`

More accurately, if you have the right actions in your `<intent-filter>`, on Android 4.1+ devices, you will find out about resize events via `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()`.

> But I can't find out how to update the widget in it.

You update it the same way you update it in `onUpdate()`. Call `updateAppWidget()` on the `AppWidgetManager` with an appropriate `RemoteViews`.

> I tried to redraw the widget by calling everything that I put in onUpdate(), but it's not working.

"it's not working" is not a particularly effective description of your symptoms.

> How can I make use of the bundle?

For a `Bundle` named `newOptions`, you can find out your new size range via:

```
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH)
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT)
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT)
```

For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/Resize) contains an `AppWidgetProvider` that simply pours those values into a string and uses that to update a `TextView`. The result looks like:

[image: Resize Widget, During Resize Operation]

Comment: Just FYI, this example doesn't work on my Galaxy S3 running build number JZ054K.I9300XXXELL4. However, it works beautifully on my Nexus 4. Thanks Mark!

Comment: My bad. onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() is not being called on resize. [Seems someone else is having this issue too](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/galaxy-s3-412-does-not-handle-app-widget-resizing-correctly/77/225524?boardName=GeneralB&startId=zzzzz~&curPage=3)

Comment: @Justin: Oh, joy. I'll try to get my hands on an S3 to chime in on the issue. Thanks!

Comment: How do you handle that situation on the S3 now? My Widget seems broken, because of a stupid Samsung bug.

Comment: @AndreasEK I have found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396045/how-to-catch-widget-size-changes-on-devices-where-onappwidgetoptionschanged-not

Comment: @frankish thanks I will try that out! How did you know about that? It seems nowhere to be documented.

Comment: @AndreasEK I logged every call to onReceive method. Be aware that this may not get called on other devices. So you may use it just to fill the holes for different devices.

Comment: So, I downloaded CommonsWare's app, and, when I place it on my home screen, the text does not immediately show up (onAppWidgetOptionsChanged() is not being called).  I tried on stock 4.2 and stock 4.3.
Any help?
Also, I posted this as a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526770/appwidgetprovider-onappwidgetoptionschanged-not-being-called-on-widget-placemen

Comment: @Justin lol, now that is odd. My collection-widget works fine on s3 but doesn't show scrollview on a nexus

Comment: Is there an official link to show all available values for the bundle to have ? Also, how come we have min&max ? the size of the widget has one width and height...